# How to add Modal dialog form to show on Spree commerce homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, spree

I need to present customers arriving to the homepage of a Spree commerce with a modal dialog form asking them to enter email address to subscribe.

I have identified fancybox jquery plugin as possible way to accomplish this but don't know where in the spree code to add this to take effect.

I see different occurrences of spree files in the bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ and in /apps in the project directory and not sure where to add the javascript.

I will very much appreciate some pointers to solving this and to clarify my confusion as i am quite new to Rails.

Thanks.

Comment: Place your javasript file in vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/ along side all.js and check if '//= require_tree .' is present in all.js file

Comment: my dirctrory goes not go futher than vendor/assets/javascripts/ and its empty. Could this have anything to do with my version of spree?

Comment: What is your Spree version?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

In versions of Spree prior to 2.2.x you would place the javascript under app/assets/javascripts/store/spree_frontend.js

In versions of Spree 2.2.x+ you would place under vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/

Comment: Hi @JDutil please do i need to create a view and a model to achieve this?

Comment: Hello, there is no spree_frontend.js file in app/assets/javascripts/store/ directory. Please is there some other place i can put this